# biological difference between 9 month and 7 month pregnanted humans

Tags: pregnancy

it possible baby born when 7 month of pregnancy, and possible when 9 month pregnancy.
what happen in additional 2 month?
what their difference. do they have different something.

Comment: The child is still developing, just as the child will continue to develop after it is born. Is there something in particular you have in mind? I don't know much about fetal development, so it may just be me, but it doesn't seem quite clear what answer you're looking for.